# Can rasam, a South Indian recipe, be boiled at high temperatures?

Tags: indian-cuisine

One of my friends said "rasam" should not be boiled at high temperatures but he hasn't given any reason for that statement.

Is it true? If so, could you give me the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Yea, you should not. The principle behind Rasam is the same as the principle behind the soup. You want the liquid to be infused with the optimum flavour from the masala, tomatoes, pepper etc. Beyond that it begins to lose its characteristic taste. Even rasam that has been heated repeatedly, tastes much worse than one that has been heated just once. If you make Rasam with whole peppers like in my place, the spiciness become unbearable if you boil it too much.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is rasam is a liquid thing with necessary ingredients added to it which doesn't need to actually be 'cooked' 
But we need to boil so as to remove the raw flavor of tamarind or tomato used in it. So if the rasam just starts boiling its enough heat to remove the raw smell and incorporate all the essential flavors to the rasam. It 'need not ' be heated beyond that as a matter of fact.

Comment: My question is whether it can be boiled at high temperature. Your answer is related whether we can cook rasam or not.

Comment: My answer is that , we can boil but just a few seconds would do. I always do that. But it need not be done for a long time like other curries or gravies. That's my point. I ve given just the explanation for that. The few seconds of boiling is needed to remove the raw smell of the ingredients. That's my understanding.

Comment: My understanding is either we can boil at high temperature for short time or we can boil at low temperature for long time. Am i right?

Comment: No. That's not it. You either keep in low flame or high flame. It should start boiling in either case at some point in time. Just keep it for few seconds and switch off. And rasam specifically does not require high temperature boiling as it just needed to remove the raw flavor as mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

never boil rasam. it becomes bland, just heat it till the fragrance comes out and it is about to simmer. if you dont believe, why not go ahead and boil at high temperature and drink it yourself. :)

Comment: Is this true across all of the numerous varieties of rasam?